# Show a ctools modal after form submit

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite, forms

I have a form:

```
//...
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Sumbit'),
);
```

I need when this form is validated and submitted then show a ctools modal.

This is my hook_menu for the modal:

```
$items['thankyou/%ctools_js'] = array(
    'title' => 'Thank you',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'thankyou_callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
ctools_include('ajax');
ctools_include('modal');

ctools_modal_add_js();
```

The callback function:

```
function thankyou_callback($js = NULL) {
  // Content that we place in the popup.
  $popup_content = t('Thank you!');

  if (!$js) {
    return $popup_content;
  }

  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');

  $output = array();
  $output[] = ctools_modal_command_display(t('Greetings'), $popup_content);

  print ajax_render($output);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

My form submit:

```
function myform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // ...
  // show my modal here
  modal.show();  // ???
}
```

Then, How I show a ctools modal after form submit?

Please, with not ajax callback.

Comment: This isn't the complete answer but this thread should help you since this operation seems was fixed a couple of years back: https://www.drupal.org/node/1482968

Comment: Basically you should do an Ajax callback in your form submit I believe, there are examples of how the others did that in the thread posted above.

Comment: @burnsjeremy thank you, but that thread not help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need call form to Popup by function [ctools_modal_form_wrapper](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!includes!modal.inc/function/ctools_modal_form_wrapper/7)

Any error, message will show in popup, to check submit success you need use statement

```
if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
    $output[] = ajax_command_replace('#modal-content', 'Thank you');
}
```

Or you can use ajax form to call ajax.

```
$form['markup'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<div id="pop-up"></div>'
  );
//You need markup for wrapper 
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Sumbit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'wrapper' => 'pop-up',
      'callback' => 'modal_form',
    ),
  );
```

And function submit form

```
function modal_form($form, &$form_state) {
  //Process data when form submit
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_modal_add_js();
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_display('Form Submit', 'Say Thank You');
  print ajax_render($commands);
  exit;
}
```